# nodejs express req.session undefined

Tags: node.js, session, express, undefined

Just can't figure this one out. Everything I find about express session says pretty much it just works, that, however, is not the case for me.

My whole app configuration

```
app.configure ->
  app.set 'port', process.env.PORT || 3000
  app.set 'views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')
  app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
  app.use express.favicon()
  app.use express.logger('dev')
  app.use express.json()
  app.use express.urlencoded()
  app.use express.methodOverride()
  app.use app.router
  app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use express.cookieParser()
  sessionStore = new express.session.MemoryStore
  app.use express.session secret: 'key', store: sessionStore
```

But the `req.session` is just `undefined`. I want to use it for user authentication - pretty basic. For some reason it turns out pretty tough for me.

I am using `express 3.5.0`.

My controller atm looks like this:

```
class AuthenticationController

  signUp: (req, res) ->
    console.log req.body._id
    console.log req.session
    res.status(200).send req.body

module.exports = AuthenticationController
```

and routes:

```
format = require './middlewares/format'
AuthenticationController = require './controller'

class Routes

  constructor: (app) ->
    throw new Error('app undefined') unless app
    @controller = new AuthenticationController
    @app = app
    route.apply @ for key, route of @routes

  routes:
    sign_up: ->
      @app.post '/sign_up', format.onlyJSON, @controller.signUp

module.exports = Routes
```

Comment: Show the code where you're using `req`?

Comment: You have `app.use app.router` before your session middleware, so all of your routes will be processed before the sessions are set up. Why have you ordered them like this?

Comment: Didn't think that mattered, actually....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) just had to move

```
app.use express.cookieParser()
sessionStore = new express.session.MemoryStore
app.use express.session secret: 'key', store: sessionStore
```

above the `app.use app.router` and it just clicked. Thanks.